# how to filter search results using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form in which results shows male and female candidates. I want to create a filter i.e on selecting male radio button, it will only show male results. But i have no idea how to proceed. I want to do it in javascript or jquery. My form is in html.

Comment: step 1: learn javascript, step 2: ???, step 3: profit

Comment: Add some attribute to all _male_ and _female_ fields and use jQuery selectors to select those.

Comment: What you have tried please send some effort along with question

Comment: Add a class to your male and another to your female fields. Then use jQuery to filter those fields. It would be helpful if you give us sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a but uncertain what you want exactly to do because no code is provided.

But as far as I understand you, you could try adding a class to all your results, it should be "male" and "female" respectively.

After this you can try to add event listener on your radio buttons(it can be any other html element) and when the button for males for example is clicked, you go and execute the following jquery command:

```
$('.female').hide();
```

then if the female button is clicked you can do:

```
$('.male').hide();
$('.female').show();
```